# Why my variable exists with interp command

Tags: tcl

I think I’ve read all the topics on this command through stackoverflow, wiki and others... English is not my native language, so I must have misunderstood.
I want independent execution context. But I don't understand when I execute this script

```
proc make {w} {
    global global_var
    
    if {[info exists global_var]} {
        puts "yes but I don't understand..."
    }
    
    set global_var $w

}

set foo [interp create -safe]
interp alias $foo hello {} make

interp eval $foo {
    hello .f1 
}

set foo1 [interp create -safe]
interp alias $foo1 hello1 {} make

interp eval $foo1 {
    hello1 .f2 
}
```

my var `global_var` exists, since I create 2 different contexts `foo` & `foo1`. My variable should never have existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alias between a source and target interpreter creates a command-level link, but the linked command (`make`) will always be executed and evaluated in the target interpreter (your main interp), and not the calling or source interpreter.

- Therefore, the `hello` call in child interp `$foo` will execute `make` in the main interp, and so does the second call `hello1` in another child interp. Hence, the variable exists.
- Besides: Your debugging `puts` would eventually fail if executed in a safe interp, because there would not be a `stdout` channel available.

You have to provide for common procedure definition of `make` in any child interp, and then execute those per-interp procs. Watch:

```
set initScript {
  proc make {w} {
    global global_var
    
    if {[info exists global_var]} {
      # yes but I don't understand...
    }
    
    set global_var $w

  }
}

set foo [interp create -safe]
interp eval $foo $initScript
interp alias $foo hello $foo make

interp eval $foo {
  hello .f1
}

set foo1 [interp create -safe]

interp eval $foo1 $initScript
interp alias $foo1 hello1 $foo1 make

interp eval $foo1 {
  hello1 .f2 
}
```

Now executing, for a second time:

```
interp eval $foo1 {
  hello1 .f2 
}
```

... will now enter your if-conditional script within `make`, as the variable was found existing in the second child interp.

---

Additional remarks:

- You may still use aliases within the child interpreters.
- You may better organise complex definition scripts as a Tcl package or Tcl module to be sourced from each child interpreter.

Comment: for your remarks , you’re thinking about that `interp eval $foo {source make.tcl}`